# How to remove this undefine index in this php sciript

Tags: php, mysql

Hope your doing fine!

I have this php scripts which enable user to search pending payments of student in database,

```
$fname="fname";
     $date="date";
     $class="class";
     $database=("mcl");
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","mcl");
     @mysql_select_db(mcl) or die( "Unable to select database");


   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$class=$_POST['class'];

$sql="SELECT           
        SUM(school_fee),SUM(trans_fee),SUM(edutrip_fee),SUM(reg_fee),
             SUM(food_fee),SUM(stationery_fee),SUM(uniform_fee),idnumber,
              edutrip_setting,stationery_setting,food_setting,uniform_setting,
              register_setting,trans_setting,fee_setting,SUM(sport_uniform),
             sport_setting,fname,class,date FROM payment_one
        WHERE fname like '%".$fname."%' AND class like '%".$class."%' AND date  
            like '%".$date."%'";

         <?php
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
?>

<tr>
    <td width="100"><?php echo $res['fname'];?></td>
     <td width="200"><?php echo $res['fee_setting']- $res['SUM(school_fee)'];?></td>
     <td width="100"><?php echo $res['trans_setting']- $res['SUM(trans_fee)'];?></td>
     <td width="200"><?php echo $res['stationery_setting']-  
     $res['SUM(stationery_fee)'];?></td>
     <td width="200"><?php echo $res['register_setting']- $res['SUM(reg_fee)'];?></td>
    <td width="10"><?php echo $res['food_setting']- $res['SUM(food_fee)'];?></td>
    <td width="10"><?php echo $res['uniform_setting']- $res['SUM(uniform_fee)'];?></td>
    <td width="10"><?php echo $res['edutrip_setting']-   
    $res['SUM(edutrip_fee)'];?>       
    </td>
    <td width="10"><?php echo $res['sport_setting']- $res['SUM(sport_uniform)'];?></td>
    <td width="30"><?php echo $res['class'];?></td>
    <td width="280" style="border-width:medium"><?php echo $res['date'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php }?>
```

This is a table

```
       $num="create table payment_one
      (id int primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      fk_id varchar (10) NULL,
      idnumber varchar (10) NULL,
      fname varchar (50) NOT NULL,
      class varchar (15) NOT NULL,
      school_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      trans_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      stationery_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      reg_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      food_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      uniform_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      edutrip_fee FLOAT(8,2),
      edutrip_name varchar (20),
      fee_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
      uniform_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
      register_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
      food_setting FLOAT(8,2),
        edutrip_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
        stationery_setting FLOAT(8,2),
        trans_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
       sport_uniform FLOAT(8,2),
       sport_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
      date date NULL)";
```

Once you look proper u may find setting fields in "payment_one" table,in  this fields carry the actual amount of money of which student suppose to pay,Example(fee_setting is 100000), this means that once I set this amount will minus the amount of school_fee which student pay.

So my Big problem here is this :

> Notice: Undefined index: SUM(school_fee)

Note: I put the SUM in order to collect all respective payment of each student so that can be Minus by 'fee_setting' in order to know how much remain by each student.

Please any one can help me to remove this Notes it real make me unhappy.

Comment: Are you actually executing a query? I can't see it. Don't use **mysql_*** functions, they are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: fyi your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: `@mysql_select_db(mcl)` This is almost a perfect example as to why you should NOT suppress error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the clean way to access it would be to create aliases for those results:

```
SELECT           
  SUM(school_fee) AS school_fee, 
  SUM(trans_fee) AS trans_fee, 
  SUM(edutrip_fee) AS edutrip_fee, 
  SUM(reg_fee) AS reg_fee,
  SUM(food_fee) AS food_fee, 
  SUM(stationery_fee) AS stationary_fee, 
  SUM(uniform_fee) AS uniform_fee, ...
```

then access them as:

```
$res['school_fee']
```

Comment: Thank u Kai Qing,it I get my desire result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the vaguely described problem correctly, it's coming from when you do the `$res['SUM(school_fee)']` in the PHP code?

You might need to do aliasing in your SQL (eg. `SELECT SUM(school_fee) AS sum_school_fees`) and that way you can access `$res['sum_school_fees']` afterwards.